# I am not able to get the file open in new window when i use window.open()

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

I am using this code to open a file, it displays the url in the console but it does not open it in a new window.

```
ft.openFile = function(id) {
  FileService.download(id).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp.headers('Content-Type'));
    var blob = new Blob([resp.data], {
      type: resp.headers('Content-Type')
    });
    var url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
    var fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(fileUrl);
    console.log(fileUrl);
})
```

Comment: when you are using winodw.open(), there might be a browser permission needed. You should have to allow the popup in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
window.open(fileUrl, '_blank'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 ft.openFile = function(id){
 FileService.download(id).then(function(resp){
    console.log(resp.headers('Content-Type'));
    var blob = new Blob([resp.data],{type: resp.headers('Content-Type')});
    var url = $window.URL||$window.webkitURL;
    var fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);

    window.open(fileUrl, '_self'); //same window

    //or

    window.open(fileUrl, '_blank'); //new window

    console.log(fileUrl);
 })
```